# QTableView, strech all section but the last one resize to content

Tags: c++, qt, qtableview

My table consists of 2 columns: the 1st one stores some strings, the other contains a checkbox only. To make my table a little bit fancy I want to stretch the whole table to the width of its view.

Using

```
setStretchLastSection(true);
```

solves the 1st problem. The table looks better, but... OK... the last column is a bit large.

Also I can use

```
setSectionResizeMode(QHeaderView::Stretch);
```

The table looks great, but... It isn't my desire. The 1st column should be optimally at least 90% of view's width and the 2nd one small since it contains one checkbox only. Additionally the table shoub be stretched to the view's width. Any Ideas?

Here is a picture just to make my question more understandable)

[image: QMainWindow, MyTableViewModel]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution:

1. Disable the stretch option for the last column

   setStretchLastSection(false);
2. Set a fixed width for the last column

   setColumnWidth(1, fixedWidth)
3. Stretch the first column

   setSectionResizeMode(0, QHeaderView::Stretch)

[a bit fancy look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RgMKa.png)